# keystroke "1" using command down - beeps instead of working

Tags: macos, focus, applescript

I'm writing a simple applescript that should focus an app and click "cmd+1".

This is what I wrote:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "appname"
        --Lobby focus
        activate
        keystroke "1" using command down
    end tell
end tell
```

But instead of working, there's one beep and the application doesn't even take focus.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't tell processes to activate. Change it to `set frontmost to true`:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set frontmost of process "Finder" to true
    keystroke "1" using command down
end tell
```

Or tell the application to activate:

```
activate application "Finder"
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "1" using command down
end tell
```

If the application has no open windows, `reopen` opens a new default window:

```
tell application "Finder"
    reopen
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "1" using command down
end tell
```